# Integration with quadratic square root

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What could be the techniques we need to use to solve this integration

$\int\dfrac{s^2\sin^2\left(s\sqrt{ as^2+bs+c}\right)}{as^2+bs+c}ds$ ?

Main issue here is the term inside $\sin^2()$. Very difficult to make it in proper form

Comment: wolfram isn't able to solve this [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2%2F%28ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%29%29sin%5E2%28x*sqrt%28ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%29%29)

Comment: Maple also doesn't find a closed form, even in special cases such as $a=c=1$, $b=0$.  I would be quite surprised if a closed form existed.

Comment: I am thinking some substitution.. some way I need to make that sin in to sin u form .. Thanks for the trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\int\dfrac{s^2\sin^2\left(s\sqrt{as^2+bs+c}\right)}{as^2+bs+c}ds$

$=\int\dfrac{s^2}{as^2+bs+c}\dfrac{1-\cos\left(2s\sqrt{as^2+bs+c}\right)}{2}ds$

$=-\int\dfrac{s^2}{2(as^2+bs+c)}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n4^ns^{2n}(as^2+bs+c)^n}{(2n)!}ds$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n-1}s^{2n+2}(as^2+bs+c)^{n-1}}{(2n)!}ds$